# What is the remainder when $45!$ is divided by $47$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

What is the remainder when $45!$ is divided by $47$ ?

---

Is there any method to approach such questions ?

Comment: What are your thoughts, Garrick?

Comment: @amWhy I guess Wilson Theorem but I don't know how to apply ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem), $46! \equiv -1 \pmod{47}$.  Thus, we have
$$
-1 \equiv 46! \equiv 46 \cdot 45! \equiv (-1) \cdot 45! \pmod{47}
$$
deduce that $45! \equiv 1 \pmod{47}$.

Comment: @amWhy I understand your frustration.  If I see a question that looks familiar, I'll look for an older question; however, this was a question I had never seen that had a quick answer, so I just went for it.  I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: I do understand. Thanks for the reply!